# Does the "Sandstorm in a Balloon" have the improved double jump?

Tags: terraria

I have both the *Cloud in a Bottle* and *Sandstorm in a Bottle*. for the latter it says it does an improved double jump which visualy, insted of just another jump you do a twirl and you seem to go much higher/further than the *Cloud in a Bottle*.

When i check the crafting recipes with the Guide both Jars can be combined with a *Shiny Red Balloon* but the descriptions for the double jump effect are the exact same.

So i am wondering, does the *Sandstorm in a Balloon* do the same improved double jump as the *Sandstorm in a Bottle* or does it do the same double jump as the *Cloud in a Bottle*

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a Sandstorm in a Balloon has an improved double jump.

Reddit user [DataNalle posted an infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgpPK.png) showing the jump heights of all jump-modifying items. As seen in the picture, the Sandstorm in a Bottle only goes up 20 tiles, while the Sandstorm in a Balloon boasts a distance of 36 tiles.

Note that the Cloud in a Bottle only goes up 11 tiles, which its *in a Balloon* variant only goes up to 19 tiles.  So it's very clear that the Sandstorm in a Balloon travels much further up than a Cloud in a Balloon.

Also consider the fact that a Red Balloon increases your jump height by 10 tiles. This means you actually lose some of the effect by having a Cloud in the Balloon, since the increase is only 8, meaning you lose 2 tiles of jump. However, the Sandstorm goes from 20 to 36, so you get an extra 6 tiles of jump height when you upgrade.

So statistics wise:

- Sandstorm upgrade from *Bottle -> Balloon* (20 - 36) = **80% increase** in jump height
- Cloud upgrade from *Bottle -> Balloon* (11 - 19) = **72% increase** in jump height

So it's very clear that the Sandstorm variants offer a great increase in jump height over the Cloud variants.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [Terraria wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sandstorm_in_a_Balloon), the Sandstorm in a Balloon keeps the "twirl" effect. In general, the respective effects stay the same, be it Cloud, Blizzard or Sandstorm.

Answer (score 1):

The *Sandstorm in a Bottle* is the Strongest out of the 3 _____s in a bottle, which are the *Cloud in a Bottle* (weakest), *Blizzard in a Bottle* (medium), and *Sandstorm in a Bottle* (strongest). If you make the *Bundle of Balloons*, this difference becomes apparent. So yes, The *Sandstorm in a Bottle* does have an improved double jump.

Answer (score -3):

Every Thing in a Balloon will retain the previous effect of its Jar counterpart.

-The Cloud in a Balloon jumps with a cloud at the users feet.
-The Blizzard in a Balloon jumps with a long snow from the users feet.
-And the Sandstorm in a balloon jumps with a twirl and sand coming from the users feet.

The only real difference between the Jars and the Balloons is that balloons can go higher. So to answer your question, the balloons DO retain they're previous effect and jump, such as the twirl, only higher.

Comment: The reason your answer gets downvoted and his doesn't is that he posted his answer more than 2 weeks ago and you didn't add anything new with your answer.